# Django/Python: < comes up as &lt; when I import it from the model object

Tags: python, django, unicode

**Revised question:**

In my dbms, I'm storing the literal `<<<firefox-image>>>`, I confirmed in Navicat and Mysql CLI that its `<<<firefox-image>>>`. When I use the Python shell and try to grab the same article entry, the outer `<>`'s get converted to `&lt;` and `&lt;`, respectively.

Snippet of me testing:

```
>>> entry = Entry.objects.filter( pub_date__lte = datetime.datetime.now() ).filter(featured=1)[0].excerpt_html
>>> entry
u'<p>\u0432\u0430\u043d.\n&lt;&lt;<firefox-image>&gt;&gt;</p>'
```

How can I get it to use the literal `<` and `>`?

**Original question**:

In my template I did this:

```
{{ entry.excerpt_html|safe|render_uploads }}
```

it complained at the `render_uploads` because I didnt load adminfiles, so I prepended

```
{% load adminfiles_tags %}
```

The error went away, but in my article excerpt it still renders `<<<firefox-image>>>` as `&lt;&lt;firefox-image&gt;&gt;`.

Comment: What type of Field is "excerpt_html"? If it's clearly stored one way in the DB, and you get something different out of the ORM, that almost has to be your Field class doing the mangling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a dumbass - I forgot to invoke `render_uploads` before storing it.

```
return markdown(render_uploads(markup))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't duplicate that symptom; the fact that you have only two less-than and greater-thans on each side makes me wonder if your inline syntax is wrong? Are there definitely three on either side in your content area?

Otherwise, I think I'd need to see more of the relevant code.